# Express: how to check if a request is coming from a React Native application?

Tags: node.js, express

How can I check if a request is coming from a React Native application?

I see different `User-Agent` headers are set in different browsers.

How can I detect if the client is an RN app using the `User-Agent` header in Node.js/Express?

Comment: Are you asking about general react native applicaiton, or about one that you can control? If the last on is the case, just add a custom http header? Otherwise its complicated and a http header can be easy faked, so i wouldnt trust that much...

Comment: I am talking about a general RN app.

Comment: @ColinWang how did you go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

as @Marc said, you can easily add a http header in a react native application, because i expect you probably want to use the backend in both platforms web and mobile development

in my case i use a custom http header

```
export const client = new GraphQLClient(
  Platform.OS === 'ios'
    ? 'http://192.168.3.50:4000/graphql'
    : 'http://192.168.3.50:4000/graphql',
  {
    credentials: 'include',
    mode: 'cors',
    headers: {
      platform: 'mobile',  // This can be also added in fetch, axios etc...
    },
  },
);
```

in your nodejs application should be something like this...

```
context: ({ req, res }: { req: Request; res: Response }) => {
        const cookies = req.headers["platform"]; // you got the value "mobile"
       
        return { req, res };
      },
```